# 特定の画面での画面回転を抑止

Tags: monaca

とある画面でのみ、画面表示回転を抑止したいのですが、そんな事は可能なのでしょうか？
もしご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授頂けますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

以下のプラグインが見つかりました。
https://github.com/yoik/cordova-yoik-screenorientation
https://github.com/cogitor/PhoneGap-OrientationLock

こちらによく似た質問があり、CSSを利用してコンテンツを無理やり回転させることで実装しているようです。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286177/cordova-ios-change-screen-orientation-to-landscape-on-a-single-page